# how to install gscam

Tags: gscam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

tried to install gscam in hydro but was unsuccessful following several answers on here for previous distributions of ros.

can anyone help me out with a simple set of terminal instructions for hydro?

Please and thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/91676/how-to-install-gscam/) by [robotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/7851/robotnewbie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-10-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After installing ros, all you should have to execute is:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-hydro-gscam
```

---

Originally posted by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) with karma: 5809 on 2013-10-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/7851/robotnewbie/) on 2013-10-16**:
thanks but after I do that, i still get these errors

when I run rosmake gscam, it gives me an error saying "mkdir: cannot create directory 'build': Permission denied.

also if I try to run the tutorial here http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition (under number 4)
I can't roscd to gscam/bin since it doesn't, also running the second command gives me an error

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-10-16**:
You don't need to build it if you install it via debian package like above.

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-10-16**:
Additionally, that tutorial is out of date and relates to an older version of gscam.

**Comment by [robotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/7851/robotnewbie/) on 2013-10-16**:
thank for your help, appreciate it.

Looking at this tutorial http://wiki.ros.org/face_recognition, (scroll down to 4 - Tutorial)  it says to do
roscd gscam/bin (but I don't have a bin folder!) and
if I try to do
rosrun gscam gscam /gscam/image_raw:=/camera/image_raw
then it gies me an error saying that GSCAM_CONFIG environment variable is not set and 'gscam_config' is not set

**Comment by [robotnewbie](https://answers.ros.org/users/7851/robotnewbie/) on 2013-10-16**:
oh was typing up my comment so didnt see your "Additionally" comment til after I posted.

should I be worred that I don't have a bin folder though?  none of the commands i find to run gscam work for me

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-10-16**:
First, the new version of gscam conforms the proper ROS camera API (http://wiki.ros.org/camera_drivers) Second, as the error says, you need to either set the $GSCAM_CONFIG environment variable or the gscam_config ROS parameter to use the program. You can see examples here ( http://github.com/ros-drivers/gscam/tree/master/examples )

**Comment by [jbohren](https://answers.ros.org/users/50/jbohren/) on 2013-10-16**:
The executables that would be built into a package's "bin" folder in a rosbuild-based package, when installed, are placed in /opt/ros/$ROS_DISTRO/lib/package-name/. The gscam executable, for example, should be in /opt/ros/hydro/lib/gscam/gscam You can examine the files installed by any package in the synaptic package manager.